# "There is currently a lease on the resource and no lease ID was specified in the request." Running several pipelines in Azure Synapse Analytics

Tags: azure, azure-synapse

I am running about 14 pipelines in ASA. Each has a similar function, essentially call an API and stores the received body. I am using a tumbling window trigger to execute these functions. What I noticed is that some of the pipelines return this error .

The linked services I used are from the Azure Data Lake Gen 2 not blob but maybe it is writing to blob storage? (I don't fully understand how this works.

> "There is currently a lease on the resource and no lease ID was specified in the request."

What I've tried is to concurrency values to 1 but I still got this error.

Comment: Can you increase the concurrency to higher number and check?

Comment: How high of a number would be good?

Comment: Since you have 14 pipelines running, try with 14

Comment: I think that did help, I also noticed a problem where when it calls the api, it would save with the same file name and it just became cluttered.

Comment: Yes. This issue is due to multiple requests being executed simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

> There is currently a lease on the resource and no lease ID was specified in the request."

- This is because the data lake/blob resource you are trying to access is locked or leased by another process or pipeline.
- Thus, you need to adjust the concurrency values to higher value to execute without any error.

[image]